# Calculating traces for triangle diagrams with massless fermions

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, feynman-diagrams, dirac-matrices, quantum-anomalies

I am following Schwarz Quantum Field Theory textbook. In particular, I am looking at triangle diagrams with massless fermions. On pg. 623 - 624 Schwarz attempts to calculate $q_\mu^1 M_{5}^{\alpha\mu\nu}$ which should be zero by the Ward Identity of QED. This gives (Eq. 30.29),

\begin{multline}
q_\mu^1 M_{5}^{\alpha\mu\nu}
=
\int
\frac{d^4 k}{(2\pi)^2}
\left[
\frac{\text{Tr}[
\gamma^\nu(\not\! k + \not\!q_2)\gamma^\alpha\gamma^5(\not\! k - \not\!q_1)
]}{(k - q_1)^2 (k + q_2)^2}
-
\frac{\text{Tr}[
\not\!k \gamma^\nu(\not\! k + \not\! q_2)\gamma^\alpha\gamma^5 
]}{k^2 (k + q_2)^2}
\right.\\[0.25cm]
\left.
+ 
\frac{
\text{Tr}[\gamma^\nu\not\!k \gamma^\alpha\gamma^5(\not\! k - \not\! q_2)]
}{k^2(k - q_2)^2}
-
\frac{\text{Tr}[
\gamma^\nu(\not\! k + \not\! q_1)\gamma^\alpha\gamma^5(\not\! k - \not\! q_2)
]}{(k + q_1)^2(k - q_2)^2}
\right].
\end{multline}

Schwarz says that after completing the traces, the result is (Eq. 30.30)
\begin{equation}
q_\mu^1 M_{5}^{\alpha\mu\nu}
=
- 4i\epsilon^{\alpha\nu\rho\sigma}
\int
\frac{d^4 k}{(2\pi)^2}
\left[
\frac{(k  - q_1)^\rho(k + q_2)^\sigma}{(k - q_1)^2(k + q_2)^2}
-
\frac{(k  - q_2)^\rho(k + q_1)^\sigma}{(k - q_2)^2(k + q_1)^2}
\right].
\end{equation}

This leads me to believe that
$$
I = \int
\frac{d^4 k}{(2\pi)^2}
\left[
-
\frac{\text{Tr}[
\not\!k \gamma^\nu(\not\! k + \not\! q_2)\gamma^\alpha\gamma^5 
]}{k^2 (k + q_2)^2}
+ 
\frac{
\text{Tr}[\gamma^\nu\not\!k \gamma^\alpha\gamma^5(\not\! k - \not\! q_2)]
}{k^2(k - q_2)^2}
\right]
=
0
$$
which I am having difficulty proving. So far, I have evaluated the traces as follows
\begin{align}
\text{Tr}[
\not\!k \gamma^\nu(\not\! k + \not\! q_2)\gamma^\alpha\gamma^5 
]
&=
\text{Tr}[
\gamma^\alpha\gamma^5  \not\!k \gamma^\nu(\not\! k + \not\! q_2)
]\\[0.25cm]
&=
-\text{Tr}[\gamma^5\gamma^\alpha\gamma^\rho\gamma^\nu\gamma^\sigma
]k_\rho(k + q_2)_\sigma\\[0.25cm]
&=
-4i\epsilon^{\alpha\rho\nu\sigma} k_\rho(k + q_2)_\sigma\\[0.25cm]
&=
4i\epsilon^{\alpha\nu\rho\sigma} k_\rho(q_2)_\sigma.
\end{align}

Similarly, we can show that
\begin{equation}
\text{Tr}[\gamma^\nu\not\!k \gamma^\alpha\gamma^5(\not\! k - \not\! q_2)] = -4i\epsilon^{\alpha\nu\rho\sigma}(q_2)_\rho k_\rho
.
\end{equation}

From here, the integral $I$ becomes,
\begin{align}
I &= -4i\epsilon^{\alpha\nu\rho\sigma}\int\frac{d^4k}{(2\pi)^4}\frac{1}{k^2}
\left[\frac{k_\rho(q_2)_\sigma}{(k + q_2)^2} + \frac{k_\sigma(q_2)_\rho}{(k - q_2)^2}\right]\\[0.25cm]
&= -4i\epsilon^{\alpha\nu\rho\sigma}\int\frac{d^4k}{(2\pi)^4}
\frac{k_\rho(q_2)_\sigma}{k^2}\left[\frac{1}{(k + q_2)^2} - \frac{1}{(k - q_2)^2}\right]
\overset{?}{=} 0.
\end{align}

Here is where I am stuck. Simplifying the term in square brackets doesn't seem to help. My only other thought is that the integrand is odd as there is a $k_\rho$ term and may vanish.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. It is potentially inconsistent to shift the integration variable $k$ of divergent integrals, cf. e.g. subsections 30.2.2-3. This is particular sensitive in a discussion of quantum anomalies from triangle diagrams!
2. Pull $(q_2)_\sigma$ outside of the integral $I$ in OP's last expression.
3. The integral now has a lower external Lorentz index $\rho$. Since the integral only depends on $q_2$, any Lorentz-covariant regularization of the integral must produce a factor $(q_2)_{\rho}$.
4. Contraction of $\epsilon^{\alpha\nu\rho\sigma} (q_2)_\sigma$ with $(q_2)_{\rho}$ then yields that $I=0$ as OP wanted to show.

Comment: Didn't knew point 1. Thanks a lot for pointing that out!

Comment: Notes for later: http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/gaugetheory.html Anomaly inflow mechanism: Sections (4.4.1) + 4.4.2 + (8.4) + 8.5.